# Estimating or Solving Two-Variable Infinite Sum

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm working on some laboratory methodology. My problem is running a procedure with a given failure rate $x$ that takes time $y$ to complete. If it fails, it needs to be run again, again with failure rate $x$.

I want to estimate for the average amount of time that a given procedure takes to complete, accounting for re-runs due to failure. I have my formula, which expands out into what's essentially a weighted average. $(k+1)y$ represents the amount of time taken, weighted by how often it will take that much time (the chance of enough failures to get to this point, minus the change of an additional failure).

$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty (k+1)(x^k-x^{k+1})y
$$

The problem I have now is that I need to estimate the value, since this will be used for comparing procedures on the drawing board as well as ones in practice.

So, long story short I have the infinite sum above, and I need to reduce it to something I can program into a computer function. $x$ and $y$ need to stay, and $k$ needs to go.

Edit: $0 < x < 1$ The series definitely converges.

Comment: i that sum, if the y is a constant number ?

Comment: if y is constant then you have two independent sum, if $abs(x)$ be lower tan 1, then you can expect an answer

Comment: Within a single instance of the formula, y is constant yes. As is x.

I'm not plotting a continuous series of values, I'm testing specific values. Which I hope makes it a more manageable problem.

Comment: the series goes to infinity if x >1

Comment: it is essential in convergence of the sum

Comment: can you determine the region of x variation ?

Comment: Edited. Yes, yes I can. Positive, non-zero, less than 1.

Comment: its a very preferable case ! wait a second !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
S_k: \sum_{k=0}^\infty x^{k}(k+1)
$$

$$
S_k: \sum_{k=0}^\infty kx^{k} +\sum_{k=0}^\infty x^{k}
$$

$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty x^{k}=\frac{1}{1-x}
$$

$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty kx^{k} = \frac{x}{(1-x)^2}
$$

you can do same things about the the second case just with k+1, imean below:

$$
 -\sum_{k=0}^\infty x^{k+1}(k+1)
$$

Comment: How would I re-insert the $y$? I said you could treat it as constant, but it's not _actually_ constant, so where did it end up?

Comment: just a simple multiplication it acts as a number in each summation

Comment: I got it, thanks. :)

Comment: it is nice ! :)